# Where are root document folder and logs after installing apache http server on debian?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I installed apache by this:

```
apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils
```

and server is running, but unfortunately when I create index.html file in /var/www there is still result: "404 Not Found".
File httpd.conf is empty and in apache.conf I don't see any folder to configure.

Answer (score 1):

logs will be found in /var/log/apache2

the default doc root is /var/www and this should be setup correctly

how are you trying to access the site in your browser?

Comment: these folders were correct previously when I first login to my server (vps) but when I remove and add apache2 (apt-get remove / apt-get install) there are not valid.

Comment: unless you edited /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default then it should work correctly, i suggest you may have another issue with your server/configuration if a remove and isntall broke your webserver

Answer (score 0):

You should check in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`. This is where you will find the DocumentRoot and other directives.

Comment: httpd.conf and all 5 folders in /etc/apache2 are empty.

Comment: How was the server installed? Did you use your favorite's distribution package manager? I think there is a deeper issue than this.

Answer (score 0):

Check configuration file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

In last lines of defualt configuration file (apache2.conf) there is an `Include` statement

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

Comment: this folder is empty after apt-get install apache2

Comment: actually I just installed apache after seeing your post and I have 000-default in sites-enabled/ . :(

Answer (score 0):

Your server does not look like it has been correctly installed. Did you get any error when you installed Debian or apache2? If so, you should re-install Debian. If apache was the one with the error, you should do (assuming you are root):

```
apt-get update ## to make sure that you have the latest repository details
apt-get upgrade ## to make sure your server is up to date (no incompatibilities or other)
apt-get purge apache2 ## completely remove apache and any other config files related to it
apt-get install apache2 ## re-install apache
```

Then, you can edit your default configurations that are found in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default, using an editor. If the config file is still missing, look back at the installation logs, maybe there was a certain error that you have missed.